# DAO class does not recognize the table name and id

Tags: android-room

I'm trying to save my images using room database.

Saving is not working. I guess my DAO class does not recognize the table name and id. Can you review the following pictures and help me to solve this issue?

```
@Entity(tableName = "my_images") 

public class MyImagesEntity {
    

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    public int image_id;
    public String image_title;
    public String image_description;
    //images/sounds are stored in database as binary large object
    public byte[] image;

    //constructor


    public MyImagesEntity(String image_title, String image_description, byte[] image) {
        this.image_title = image_title;
        this.image_description = image_description;
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

The @Dao annotated interface

```
@Dao
public interface MyImagesDao {


    @Insert
    void insert(MyImagesEntity myImagesEntity);

    @Delete
    void delete(MyImagesEntity myImagesEntity);

    @Update
    void update(MyImagesEntity myImagesEntity);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM my_images ORDER BY image_id ASC")
    LiveData<List<MyImagesEntity>> getAllImages();

}
```

The dependencies

```
     def room_version = "2.4.2"

implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

def lifecycle_version = "2.5.0-alpha03"

// ViewModel
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
// LiveData
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:$lifecycle_version"

// Annotation processor
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Saving is not working.

Using the code you have supplied, I don't believe that your issue is that data is not being saved as using the following additional code :-

```
@Database(entities = {Data.class/*<<<<< due to test using a hijacked project*/,MyImagesEntity.class}, exportSchema = false, version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
   abstract DataDao getDataDao(); //<<<<< due to test using a hijacked project
   abstract MyImagesDao getMyImagesDao();

   private static volatile AppDatabase instance = null;

   static AppDatabase getAppDatabase(Context context) {
      if (instance == null) {
         instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                 .allowMainThreadQueries()
                 .build();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

and the following in an activity:-

```
    db = AppDatabase.getAppDatabase(this);
    myImagesDao = db.getMyImagesDao();

    myImagesDao.insert(new MyImagesEntity("Image001","Image 1 description",new byte[]{10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17}));
    myImagesDao.insert(new MyImagesEntity("Image002","Image 2 description",new byte[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,}));
    for(MyImagesEntity mie: myImagesDao.getAllImagesOther()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","Image is " + mie.image_description + " Description is " + mie.image_description);
    }
```

with **getAllImagesOther** being (without LiveData) :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM my_images ")
List<MyImagesEntity> getAllImagesOther();
```

Then the result is :-

```
D/DBINFO: Image is Image 1 description Description is Image 1 description
D/DBINFO: Image is Image 2 description Description is Image 2 description
```

and using **App Inspection** you can see that the data has been added :-

[image]

Therefore I believe that you issues is with how your are observing (or not) the LiveData. I'd suggest using **App Inspection** to see if the data is being saved.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My app works perfectly. By the way, can you give me a general guideline about debugging, and testing in an efficient way?

Comment: @ProvatPaul, first if the answer helped you may consider ticking it. Ok debugging,  two techniques have been shown. Logging messages and viewing them via the log and for SQLite Databases (room is a wrapper around SQLite) App Inspection.  Here's two links that you may find informative in this regard.  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/ and https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database